# How to calculate accelerometer sensor rotational speed to KM/H

Tags: accelerometer

I am using `BMA250E` accelerometer and I setting chip is `+/- 16G`
The accelerometer is put on the bicycle wheel hub and each `10ms` I read the chip and do these calculate.

3 axis total g force is do these like below:

```
force = sqrt( ((double)x_g * x_g) + ((double)y_g * y_g) +((double)z_g * z_g) );
```

I got the accelerometer `g force` and which is follow the wheel rotation speed up or down.
But I don't know how to calculate what the g force I got to `KM/H`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between acceleration (which is proportional to force in most cases) and speed?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the speed of the bike or the speed of the point on the wheel where you have fixed the accelerometer?

Comment: Sorry reply so late,
1. I don't know they are different.
2. I mount the accelerometer on wheel hub and I want to calculate the bike speed when It has rode on the road.

Comment: The lowest part of a wheel does not move at all, the topside moves twice as fast as the bike. Some parts of the whell move move partially upwards, some downwards... If you mount right on the axle it moves exactly as fast as the bike but does not experience any acceleration. The acceleration of the point on any other part of the whell is always straight towards the axle. The speed is the integrated acceleration over time... So please, give more details about what you measure, with sequences of examples. Abd experiment with integrating it, 3D...

Comment: Integration acceleration is probably unsatisfying, it can drift off target. Did you consider just counting cycles/time and multiply by circumference of the wheel?

Comment: Hi,
I do like this now.
I mount acc on the wheel hub and X axis will be sine wave.
I running 15KM and read the force once. 16KM and read the force....
until 100KM.
but there is one problem when speed under 15km the force is same.

Comment: about the cycles/time  I use speed value calculate it.

Comment: I do not really get the recent comments. At first (before edits) it seemed that you confirmed the counting solution... Please be careful not to change the question (e.g. do not go from "how to generally" to "special problem below 15km/h). But do feel free to add more details and explanations to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from measured acceleration to speed you would theoretically have to integrate acclearation over time.
That would however be at risk of suffering from growing errors, because a bike in constant motion experiences the same acceleration (at e.g. the frame) as a static bike.
Points on the wheel experience dynamically changing acceleration, which however (while moving constantly) also integrates to zero, 3-dimensionally.

A different approach is to count cycles/time and multiply by circumference of the wheel the accelerometer is attached to.

(You already indicated that you did so, this is mostly for getting the question out of the list of unanswered questions.)